# create custom rule condition

Tags: rules

I want to create a custom rule condition and a custom rule action. For this reason I created a custom module. Despite I found some info on creating the custom rule action, I cant find anything about the custom rule condition.

How should I created and what files do I need to create inside the custom module?

Comment: Did you look into [hook_rules_condition_info](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules/tree/rules.api.php?id=7.x-2.12#n279)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it, instead of creating a new module, I just created a new condition file inside rules/src/Plugin/Condition.